# Htaccess Rewrite condition influencing CAPTCHA verification on AJAX contact form

Tags: php, ajax, .htaccess, jquery, contact-form

I'm using a simple php AJAX form and it works perfectly.
Recently, in order to make my URLs more Search Engine Friendly, I used the .htaccess file to remove the .php extension and now the form CAPTCHA verification is never verifying.

Do you know what might have gone wrong?

The form is jigowatt's HTML5 AJAX Contact Form.
Here is the htaccess code lines to remove the extension php I'm using:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

I'm wondering if there's a workaround on this. I've tried unsuccessfully to leave the Contact form url with the .php extension but it doesn't work.

Thank you

Comment: That ReWrite condition is fine for when you want to deliver the page without .php but where's the handler for when you request a page without the .php extension? If the ajax call uses `/` then it'll send the request to that page, if no handler is present, the server doesn't know how to handle the response. Can you please check the network tab or console to identify what the response from the ajax call is before we move on.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, I used the Chrome developers tools to check the console. here's the message on the log: XHR finished loading: "http://www.merodivingcenter.com/verify/ajax_check".               send jquery-latest.js:8706
jQuery.extend.ajax jquery-latest.js:8136
(anonymous function) jquery.jigowatt.js:48
jQuery.event.dispatch jquery-latest.js:5095
elemData.handle jquery-latest.js:4766
jQuery.event.trigger jquery-latest.js:5007
jQuery.event.simulate jquery-latest.js:5330
handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try replacing these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,NE,L]
```

with

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|HEAD)\s/(.+)\.php[^\s]* [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%2 [R=301,NE,L]
```

So that POST requests (assuming that's how the AJAX call is working) won't get redirected.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy not sure, but when I try it in my test platform, it doesn't work.

Comment: This is it, worked like a charm! the AJAX indeed uses POST requests. So this rule says to remove the .php from the Url except when its a POST url?

Comment: @pedroteixeira07 It actually says remove the .php from the URL *only* if the request is GET or HEAD. So for a POST request, the rule isn't applied (so no redirect).